# Ruby unable to execute shell command from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I  have the following command in one of my scripts:

```
`aws elb describe-instance-health --region eu-west-1 --load-balancer-name FooBar --instances i-05swhkqp'`
```

When this executes or I execute it from the Rails console, I get the following error and the script breaks:

```
A client error (InvalidClientTokenId) occurred when calling the DescribeInstanceHealth operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
=> ""
```

But when I execute it from bash, I get the response I expect:

```
{
    "InstanceStates": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-05swhkqp",
            "ReasonCode": "N/A",
            "State": "InService",
            "Description": "N/A"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to include it in my Ruby script or on the Rails console, so that the command can be executed?

Comment: Usually when something works in shell but breaks from inside code it's because of missing environment information or permissions caused by the code running as a different user than you run the code under.

Comment: It looks like this error message would get thrown if you ran any shell command. Why don't you try running something simple like "puts `ls`" and see if you get the same error. That's a really complicated shell command to use as an example if `ls` doesn't work either.

Comment: ls, git status all work...

Comment: Hint: Where is your client token ID defined?

Comment: @CodeGnome do you mean aws key and secret? They are defined here: `~/.aws/credentials`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I had old credentials set in `.rbenv-vars` that needed to be updated.